# Redux toolkit - addCase cannot be called with two reducers for the same action type

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

```
import { createAsyncThunk,createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import axios from "axios"
import apiHandler from "../../api/apiHandler"

const initialState = {
    breakingNews:[],
    general:[],
    technology:[],
    sports:[],
    business:[],
    status:'idle',
    error:null
}

export const fetchBreakingNewsData = createAsyncThunk('news/breakingNews',apiHandler.getBreakingNewsData)
export const fetchGeneralNewsData = createAsyncThunk('news/generalNews',apiHandler.getCategoryNewsData('general'))
export const fetchTechnologyNewsData = createAsyncThunk('news/technologyNews',apiHandler.getCategoryNewsData('technology'))
export const fetchSportsNewsData = createAsyncThunk('news/sportsNews',apiHandler.getCategoryNewsData('sports'))
export const fetchBusinessNewsData = createAsyncThunk('news/businessNews',apiHandler.getCategoryNewsData('business'))




const newsSlice = createSlice({
    name:'news',
    initialState,
    extraReducers(builder){
        builder
        .addCase(fetchBreakingNewsData.pending, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'loading'
        })
        .addCase(fetchBreakingNewsData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'succeeded'
          // Add any fetched posts to the array
          state.breakingNews = state.breakingNews.concat(action.payload)
        })
        .addCase(fetchBreakingNewsData.rejected, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'failed'
          state.error = action.error.message
        })
        .addCase(fetchGeneralNewsData.pending, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'loading'
        })
        .addCase(fetchGeneralNewsData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'succeeded'
          // Add any fetched posts to the array
          state.general = state.general.concat(action.payload)
        })
        .addCase(fetchGeneralNewsData.rejected, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'failed'
          state.error = action.error.message
        })
        .addCase(fetchTechnologyNewsData.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'loading'
          })
          .addCase(fetchTechnologyNewsData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'succeeded'
            // Add any fetched posts to the array
            state.technology = state.technology.concat(action.payload)
          })
          .addCase(fetchTechnologyNewsData.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'failed'
            state.error = action.error.message
          })
          .addCase(fetchSportsNewsData.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'loading'
          })
          .addCase(fetchSportsNewsData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'succeeded'
            // Add any fetched posts to the array
            state.sports = state.sports.concat(action.payload)
          })
          .addCase(fetchSportsNewsData.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'failed'
            state.error = action.error.message
          })
          .addCase(fetchBreakingNewsData.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'loading'
          })
          .addCase(fetchBusinessNewsData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'succeeded'
            // Add any fetched posts to the array
            state.business = state.business.concat(action.payload)
          })
          .addCase(fetchBusinessNewsData.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'failed'
            state.error = action.error.message
          })
    }
})

export default newsSlice.reducer
```

Please help me with the following error.
And if multiple api calls add cases is not possible in createSlice and how can we do it with redux toolkit.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: addCase cannot be called with two reducers for the same action type

Answer (score 0):

I would like a different approach see if that works for you.

Separating the builder from the addCase. Can you please try and let me know

```
const newsSlice = createSlice({
    name:'news',
    initialState,
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
        .addCase(fetchBreakingNewsData.pending, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'loading'
        })
        .addCase(fetchBreakingNewsData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'succeeded'
          // Add any fetched posts to the array
          state.breakingNews = state.breakingNews.concat(action.payload)
        })
        .addCase(fetchBreakingNewsData.rejected, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'failed'
          state.error = action.error.message
        })
        .addCase(fetchGeneralNewsData.pending, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'loading'
        });
        

       builder
       .addCase(fetchGeneralNewsData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'succeeded'
          // Add any fetched posts to the array
          state.general = state.general.concat(action.payload)
        })
        .addCase(fetchGeneralNewsData.rejected, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'failed'
          state.error = action.error.message
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what [@lost_in_magento](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3639575/lost-in-magento) mentioned is correct. But if you are still seeing that error you may instead of chaining them together create each addCase on the builder instance like the following:

```
...
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    // fetchBreakingNewsData
    builder.addCase(fetchBreakingNewsData.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.status = 'loading'
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchBreakingNewsData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.status = 'succeeded'
      // Add any fetched posts to the array
      state.breakingNews = state.breakingNews.concat(action.payload)
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchBreakingNewsData.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.status = 'failed'
      state.error = action.error.message
    });
    
    // fetchGeneralNewsData
    builder.addCase(fetchGeneralNewsData.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.status = 'loading'
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchGeneralNewsData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.status = 'succeeded'
      // Add any fetched posts to the array
      state.general = state.general.concat(action.payload)
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchGeneralNewsData.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.status = 'failed'
      state.error = action.error.message
    });
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you have fetchBreakingNewsData.pending in there twice. I assume you meant fetchBusinessNewsData.pending the second time.

```
import { createAsyncThunk,createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import axios from "axios"
import apiHandler from "../../api/apiHandler"

const initialState = {
    breakingNews:[],
    general:[],
    technology:[],
    sports:[],
    business:[],
    status:'idle',
    error:null
}

export const fetchBreakingNewsData = createAsyncThunk('news/breakingNews',apiHandler.getBreakingNewsData)
export const fetchGeneralNewsData = createAsyncThunk('news/generalNews',apiHandler.getCategoryNewsData('general'))
export const fetchTechnologyNewsData = createAsyncThunk('news/technologyNews',apiHandler.getCategoryNewsData('technology'))
export const fetchSportsNewsData = createAsyncThunk('news/sportsNews',apiHandler.getCategoryNewsData('sports'))
export const fetchBusinessNewsData = createAsyncThunk('news/businessNews',apiHandler.getCategoryNewsData('business'))




const newsSlice = createSlice({
    name:'news',
    initialState,
    extraReducers(builder){
        builder
        .addCase(fetchBreakingNewsData.pending, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'loading'
        })
```

''' The above line is duplicated below, see break in code.'''

```
.addCase(fetchBreakingNewsData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  state.status = 'succeeded'
  // Add any fetched posts to the array
  state.breakingNews = state.breakingNews.concat(action.payload)
})
.addCase(fetchBreakingNewsData.rejected, (state, action) => {
  state.status = 'failed'
  state.error = action.error.message
})
.addCase(fetchGeneralNewsData.pending, (state, action) => {
  state.status = 'loading'
})
.addCase(fetchGeneralNewsData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  state.status = 'succeeded'
  // Add any fetched posts to the array
  state.general = state.general.concat(action.payload)
})
.addCase(fetchGeneralNewsData.rejected, (state, action) => {
  state.status = 'failed'
  state.error = action.error.message
})
.addCase(fetchTechnologyNewsData.pending, (state, action) => {
    state.status = 'loading'
  })
  .addCase(fetchTechnologyNewsData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    state.status = 'succeeded'
    // Add any fetched posts to the array
    state.technology = state.technology.concat(action.payload)
  })
  .addCase(fetchTechnologyNewsData.rejected, (state, action) => {
    state.status = 'failed'
    state.error = action.error.message
  })
  .addCase(fetchSportsNewsData.pending, (state, action) => {
    state.status = 'loading'
  })
  .addCase(fetchSportsNewsData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    state.status = 'succeeded'
    // Add any fetched posts to the array
    state.sports = state.sports.concat(action.payload)
  })
  .addCase(fetchSportsNewsData.rejected, (state, action) => {
    state.status = 'failed'
    state.error = action.error.message
  })
  .addCase(fetchBreakingNewsData.pending, (state, action) => {
    state.status = 'loading'
  })
```

''' The above line is the duplicate and should be:'''

```
  .addCase(fetchBusinessNewsData.pending, (state, action) => { 
    state.status = 'loading' })
```

'''     '''

```
          .addCase(fetchBusinessNewsData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'succeeded'
            // Add any fetched posts to the array
            state.business = state.business.concat(action.payload)
          })
          .addCase(fetchBusinessNewsData.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'failed'
            state.error = action.error.message
          })
    }
})

export default newsSlice.reducer
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).